# Clang says usage of is_same_v<int, double> is not constexpr, not sure how it is not

Tags: c++, c++17

I have this following code which compiles fine in gcc but not clang inside of some `.cpp` file (and is the only text in that file):

```
#include <type_traits>

static constexpr int howIsThisPossible() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, int>) {
        return 42;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, double>) {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

I get

> ```
> error: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression
>
>    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, double>) {
>
>                         ^
> ```

I don't understand how it is not constexpr when the definition of `is_same_v` is:

```
template <typename _Tp, typename _Up>
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<_Tp, _Up>::value;
```

What am I doing wrong/not understand?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me using clang, perhaps the standard library that is being used is mixed up or something like that.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of clang are you using? Are you using libc++ or libstdc++, and in which version?

Comment: I was able to repro with Clang 6.0, 7.0 seems fine. See https://godbolt.org/z/YCCZCl . Furthermore if I switch the conditions, the code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/EfmoUo . Bug of an old compiler with unstable implementation of C++17?

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts What you said is the answer. If you wanted to make a full post, I will accept it as the correct one. I am [was as of now] on Clang 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to repro with Clang 6.0. Clang 7.0 seems fine. See https://godbolt.org/z/YCCZCl . Furthermore if I switch the conditions, the code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/EfmoUo . I think it might be an issue of an old compiler with unstable implementation of C++17. I suggest you upgrade to a newer version of the compiler.